# How to make a type with date field deserializable from json

Tags: haskell, aeson

I need to define data type that would have `date` field and deserialize it from json. Here's my attempt.

```
data Some = Some { date :: Data.Time.Calendar.Day } deriving (Show, Generic) 

instance FromJSON Day where
     parseJSON (Object x) = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%F" <$> x .: (pack "date")
```

Here's errors.

```
• Couldn't match type ‘m0 t0’ with ‘Day’
  Expected type: aeson-1.2.3.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Parser Day
    Actual type: aeson-1.2.3.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Parser
                   (m0 t0)
• In the expression:
    parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%F" <$> x .: (pack "date")
  In an equation for ‘parseJSON’:
      parseJSON (Object x)
        = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%F" <$> x .: (pack "date")
  In the instance declaration for ‘FromJSON Day’
```

I find it very strange that I can't find any data type with exposed constructor for creating `Date` objects. And I can't find the function that would parse `Date` from `String`

Comment: What `Date` type are you talking about?

Comment: It's hypothetical `Date`. As I've said I couldn't find any package that has it.

Comment: What is missing in `parseTimeM`?

Answer (score 3):

And for reference a fully working code example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Datetimetest where

import Data.Time.Format
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text
import Data.Maybe

newtype Some = Some { date :: Day } deriving Show

instance FromJSON Some where
  parseJSON (Object x) = (x .: pack "date") >>= \v -> Some <$> parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%F" v

test :: Some
test = fromJust $ (decode "{\"date\":\"1999-12-01\"}" :: Maybe Some)
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseTimeM` has type `(Monad m, ParseTime t) => ... -> m t`, which if you specialize it at `Day`, is `... -> m Day`, so you need to chain monadic actions (with `m ~ Parser`) or unwrap `m` somehow (e.g., `m ~ Maybe`).

```
(x .: pack "date") >>= parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%F"
```

Also, `Day` already has an instance, that parses the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: What instance are you talking about?

Comment: [`FromJSON Day`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.3.0/docs/src/Data-Aeson-Types-FromJSON.html#line-1682)